# Reading objects from a file and adding them to an array

Tags: java

I'm trying to read objects from a file then add them to an Array List of Ticket. But it's not working. May I please know where's the problem?

```
public void writeTicketToFile(Ticket ticket) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("tickets.txt");
        ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        objectOut.writeObject(ticket.toString());
        objectOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

public void readTicketFromFile(){
    ArrayList<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<Ticket>();
    try {
        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(new File("tickets.txt"));
        ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
        Ticket ticket;
        while (ticket=oi.readObject() != null){
            tickets.add((Ticket)oi.readObject());
        }
        System.out.println(tickets);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: How it is not working? Bare in mind that Ticket needs to implement Serializable interface for writing tickets to some file.

Comment: Do not `writeObject(ticket.toString())` as this converts your `ticket` to a string, but this string cannot be parsed back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of issues here:

Make sure your Ticket implements `Serializable` interface for writing/reading objects from/to file as in this simple example:

```
public class Ticket implements Serializable{

private String name;
private LocalDateTime issued;

public Ticket() {
}

public Ticket(String name, LocalDateTime issued) {
    this.name = name;
    this.issued = issued;
}

/**
 * @return the name
 */
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * @param name the name to set
 */
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * @return the issued
 */
public LocalDateTime getIssued() {
    return issued;
}

/**
 * @param issued the issued to set
 */
public void setIssued(LocalDateTime issued) {
    this.issued = issued;
}
```

}

---

Now pay attention to while writing tickets to a file to write them one at a time. You can achieve it by iterating thru your list of tickets and writing it one at a time, something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tickets.size(); i++) {
                    objectOut.writeObject(tickets.get(i));
                }
```

---

Also, make sure to close your `ObjectInputStream` after reading as it will surely throw `EOFException` at the end, take a look at implementation of it in `readTicketFromFile` method.

---

```
public class SerializationAndDeserializationOfTicket {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Ticket> listOfTickets = new ArrayList<>();
        listOfTickets.add(new Ticket("Concert 1", LocalDateTime.now()));
        listOfTickets.add(new Ticket("Concert 2", LocalDateTime.now()));
        listOfTickets.add(new Ticket("Concert 3", LocalDateTime.now()));

        writeTicketToFile(listOfTickets);

        readTicketFromFile();
    }

    public static void writeTicketToFile(List<Ticket> tickets) {

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("tickets.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            for (int i = 0; i < tickets.size(); i++) {
                objectOut.writeObject(tickets.get(i));
            }
            objectOut.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("JVM reported an IO exception. Please, take a look.");
        }
    }

    public static void readTicketFromFile() {
        ArrayList<Ticket> tickets = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(new File("tickets.txt"));
            ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
            while (true) {
                try {

                    Ticket ticket = (Ticket) oi.readObject();
                    tickets.add(ticket);
                    System.out.println(ticket.getName() + " " + ticket.getIssued());
                } catch (EOFException ex) {
                    oi.close();
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("JVM reported an IO/ClassNotFound exception. Please, take a look.");
    }
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU IT WORKED

Answer (score 1):

One of your main problems lies here:

```
while (ticket=oi.readObject() != null){
  tickets.add((Ticket)oi.readObject());
}
```

Compare the fact that you're trying to read a `Ticket` object out of a file with the way you're writing the `Ticket` to the file:

```
objectOut.writeObject(ticket.toString());
```

As you can see, you're converting the `Ticket` to a `String` and writing the `String` to the file. Then when you try to read, you're trying to read a `Ticket`. Instead, you should read a `String`, and then convert the `String` into a `Ticket` in code.

If `Ticket` is serializable, you may instead just be able to remove `.toString()` from the write step, but I've never worked with object streams, so I can't say 100% if that will work.

Comment: I removed the toString() and the object was read, but now, it is only reading one object not all of them that are in the file (or most probably only writing one object)

Comment: Glad to hear that worked. This sounds like a different issue, which should probably be a separate question. The code you've provided just shows methods for writing and reading, but not the implementation where the writing is happening. If you think you should be writing more than one `Ticket`, you'll have to show where that's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the Ticket objects into an ArrayList and write the list (instead of each object one by one) as a single object. Then read the list from the file in your `readTicketFromFile()` method as :

```
 ArrayList<Ticket> ticketsList = (ArrayList<Ticket>)oi.readObject();
```